# Is this a safe way to prevent sql injections?

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection

I need some opinions about my php coding. I'm specially curious if this is safe against sql injections. Apparently it seems to be, but I might be wrong.

And what do you think of this "style" of coding, as in, is it acceptable or really bad practice ?

```
$validinputs = array(1,9,21,'a','b');

if(in_array($_GET['search'], $validinputs))
{
  $queryfilter = " = " . $_GET['search'];
}
else
{
  $queryfilter = "IS NOT NULL";
}

(...)

$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field` {$queryfilter}";
```

Thanks!

EDIT: In this case i compare with $validinputs because these are the only valid search terms for that field, any other search term would return nothing.

Comment: You want to whitelist every possible search term? Give it up and use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is acceptable but not good practice at all. Why don't you use the standard SQL escape functions? These are really powerful and maintainable when wrapped in a class. I don't think that someone wants to maintain your application / script when you need to escape your strings this way that often. Probably causing a huge mess.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd use stored procedures and your query would look like so...

```
$query = "call find_in_table('" . $_GET['search'] . "')";
```

... but since you have a list of acceptable inputs and are very strictly filtering them before passing them into a query string, I would say you're quite safe from SQL injection and using a stored procedure would be a performance enhancement for you more so than a security feature.

Comment: why do you call it "ideally"?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, because it's difficult to inject malicious SQL into a stored procedure unless this stored procedure uses dynamic code which includes unfiltered user input by the nature of how s stored procedure would work. Using just dynamic SQL increases the chances that a missed validation would allow malicious code to slip in.

Comment: Stored Procedure != Prepared Statement.

Comment: @gfish3000: The point is, stored procedures are not inherently secured against injection when using dynamic variables, whereas prepared statements are.

Comment: @TheBlueDog, if you read my comment this is exactly what I said. No, stored procedures are not inherently invulnerable against SQL injection, but they make it more difficult if they don't rely on a lot of dynamic SQL which is very trusting of user input because the odds are skewed towards a malicious attempt breaking the statement rather than executing as part of it.

Comment: @gfish3000 I guess the problem is that you said that stored procedures are to 'ideally' be used, while stored procedures are not an ideal for a long time already...

Comment: Yeah, that was kinda how I read it. I'm not about to get into a fight over it though.

Comment: There is no point to do something "more difficult" if it's already invulnerable. Learn formal logic